# Android Studio Github Library

Tags: git, github, android-studio

I would like to clone the source of a github library to use within my Android Studio Project. I want to modify the library source and have git track the changes to push back to github.

So far I have forked the repository so I can modify the source as needed. However, I can't figure out how to clone it to my local computer and get that clone to be a library project of my Android Studio app.

I'm new to Android Studio, so I'm sure I just don't know what it expects in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone your fork locally with command lines
Otherwise you can use your IDE:

**VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git.**

Then provide the URL of your fork, the local folder where to put the project and the project name.
Android Studio will detect gradle's files and will build the project.

**EDIT:**

Then if it is a library, you can use it in another project changing your **settings.gradle** in the main project.

```
include ':library1'
project(':library1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Other Project/Library')
```

In the dependencies block of a module's build file (main project), you need to reference a module

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library1')
}
```

Comment: That seems to create a new project, not a library of my project.

Comment: I had to change what you had. Does this seem okay? 
In settings.gradle: 

include ':app', ':MapboxAndroidSDK'

project(':MapboxAndroidSDK').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../mapbox-android-sdk/MapboxAndroidSDK/')

And in app/build.gradle:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Built from local mapbox source files.
    compile project(':MapboxAndroidSDK')
}